# How to set up autotest to rerun only failing rspec examples

Tags: ruby, rspec, autotest

My impression of how autotest is intended to work (based on the [cucumber github wiki](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Autotest-Integration), and other stuff online) is that it should rerun red examples until they pass. My problem is that it reruns all examples in the spec file where a failing example is found, including passing ones. I'd rather not waste time rerunning passing examples while fixing a failing one. Can autotest be configured so only the failing examples are run?

Comment: Have you since (a) upgraded RSpec, (b) upgraded Rails, and (c) installed gem `guard-rspec` instead? Autotest is not used as much with the newer RSpec versions, to my understanding.

Comment: Yeah, running things manually seems to work well enough for my purposes. I should mention that guard strikes me as an obsolete suggestion... I've switched off it to zeus a while back, and use spring now that I've gone through the rails 4 upgrade. Ahh, the joys of keeping up... </sarc>

Comment: guard-rspec is not really obsolete.  Spork and its guard plugin is, however. Are you still using autotest?

Answer (score 0):

You need the [rspec-retry](https://github.com/y310/rspec-retry) gem. Here are some examples from the docs on how to implement it:

Apply it in a `configure` block covering your entire test-suite...

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.verbose_retry = true # show retry status in spec process
    config.default_retry_count = 3
end
```

Or apply it unit-by-unit...

```
it 'should randomly succeed', :retry => 3 do
    expect(rand(2)).to eq(1)
end
```